# Table view cell only masks correctly after scrolling off and then back on

Tags: ios, uitableview, calayer

I'm modifying a table view cell during a call to `tableView:cellForIndexPath`, but the modifications do not appear until the cell is scrolled off and then back on. I realize that I can modify the .xib file or can alloc/init a cell rather than calling `dequeue`, but I'd like to understand what is going on.

The changes involve masking the cell to achieve rounded bottom corners. If I set the corner radius instead (i.e. `cell.layer.cornerRadius = ...`), which rounds all the corners, I don't see the problem.

**Update**:

I didn't post the code initially because it was proprietary, involved a lot of complexity and I thought the question was a reasonable one in absence of any specifics. In light of the responses, though, here is a reduced fragment which exhibits the problem, with the only change being the actual cell identifier. I also updated the description/question to simplify the scenario.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TheCorrectCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4., 4.)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?(someone with your rep should know this by now?) Which language are you using? This is almost definitely due to reusing the cell incorrectly.

Comment: I tried the above code and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Are you still looking for more information/a different solution than the one provided below?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin : Is your masking issue fixed or not ? I updated my answer with proper explanation for willDisplayCell.

Comment: @Firo @technerd I was able to achieve the result I was seeking with the use of `willDisplayCell`, but I'm still looking for confirmation that it cannot be done solely with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and for as much information as I can get regarding why this is so.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I also had no problem with your above code (rounding bottom edges in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Since it is not working for you, try rounding `cell.contentView.layer` rather than the cell itself.

Answer (score 26):

Your code working fine . But if you still facing Corner radius issue in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` then try in `willDisplayCell:` .  I tried in both methods and working fine.

`willDisplayCell:`

> Tells the delegate the table view is about to draw a cell for a
>   particular row.
>  
>   A table view sends this message to its delegate just
>   before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to
>   customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives
>   the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier
>   by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the
>   delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame
>   properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.
>   Here is my code.

According to me, Apple provide two different  set of methods (Protocol) named `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to manage UITableView.

**UITableViewDataSource** : Data source provides actual data for cell to fill in the details.

**UITableViewDelegate** :  At the other end delegate is responsible for give information about visual layout of tableview and handles user interaction.

So, conclusion is that DataSource mainly deal with content(Data) of table and Delegate deal with presentation and interaction of tableview component.

Lets come to way we dealing with TableView.

We all are very personal with UITableViewDataSource  method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, This method is responsible for to create or reuse valid UITableViewCell with proper detailed information for each index path.What we tend to do cell layout configuration and UI modification in this method.

After `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, the system does a layout configuration, then calls `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method before cells display on screen.

So we can use this method for view configuration of Tableview cell(May be, Apple propose this method for us!!!).

So I persionally prefer to use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to create cell and left cell UI configuration task for `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`  method.

Apply mask in `willDisplayCell:`

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
```

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *identifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row : %ld ", (long)indexPath.section];
return cell;
}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Did you try including the masking in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`? If so, did it work? That was what my question was about, although I'm happy to receive the recommendation to use the `willDisplayCell` variant instead.

Comment: It also works with  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Ok, I tried `willDisplayCell` and it indeed fixed the problem. Are you SURE you were able to get the desired results (i.e. successful modification of the mask prior to scrolling) without implementing `willDisplayCell`? The code you showed above did not reflect any mask modification in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: willDisplayCell is display customisation  delegate method of UITableViewDelegate. So you can perform UI modification before your cell display on screen.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and it appears likely you'll get the bounty, but I don't feel like I've received an answer to my question of whether use of `willDisplayCell` is required in order to address this issue or whether you were able to get it to work without it. If you were able to get it to work without it, then I remain interested in knowing why it didn't work in my situation.

Comment: why would you add bounty, if you are not ready to give it?.. solution of @technert is absolutely correct -- you should never do anything in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, apart from returning the cell. everything should ALWAYS be done in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @OlDor: Peter Alvin explicitly said "I'd like to understand what is going on." He did not ask for a solution, but for an explanation, and it has not been given up to now.

Answer (score 6):

Reload the tableView in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method will make it to work.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Reason** why your code not worked:
Actually, as per view life cycle, the methods are called in following manner, `init`,`loadView`,`viewDidLoad`,`viewWillAppear`,`viewWillLayoutSubviews`(called more than once),`viewDidLayoutSubviews`(called multiple time) and lastly`viewDidAppear`.

Now, actually the tableview get loaded in method `viewDidLoad`, whereas the autolayout constraints that you apply were going to be applied after that method. Thats why, it is not showing expected result. Reloading it again after autolayout constraints get applied make it work. Thats'why above code will surely work.

One more point to note: In storyboard if you have designed your viewController by using iphone 5 size and then if you run the code in iphone 5, then without reloading it, it must work, but if you run it in any other sized viewController, then it will not work. The reason behind it is, `viewDidLoad` method get called, then any view have size that was in its storyboard.

If you have any doubts, let me know

Answer (score 5):

```
Approach - 1 reload cell in viewWillAppear with delay mathod

func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{ 
   super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.10, execute: {
        self.tableView.reloadData() }) 
}

Approach - 2 Draw in GCD

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TheCorrectCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4., 4.)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.layer.mask = maskLayer;

});
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Drawing in GCD was the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your issue on iOS 9.2, as your code is working fine for me.

If you are supporting older versions, I believe the issue you are facing is related to the cell's initial width not corresponding to the tableView's width. Before a cell is laid out, its initial width was based on its Storyboard width (which differs from the actual screen width).

What happens is that your shapeLayer mask starts out out with the wrong bounds, so the mask won't appear correctly *until* the cell is reused.  At that point, since the cell has been laid out, its width is now correct, the new mask's bounds are correct, and the proper effect is achieved.

While you can try to perform layout in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it involves a bit more code to handle edge cases like initial cell width issues.

It's a lot easier to apply the mask **after the cell has been laid out**, such as [technerd suggested in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35029929/4151918).

That's the explanation for the problem.

> The changes involve masking the cell to achieve rounded bottom corners. If I set the corner radius instead (i.e. cell.layer.cornerRadius = ...), which rounds all the corners, I don't see the problem.

Since that doesn't involve adding a shape layer with a specific frame size, you won't run into an issue.  The cell's layer will be the proper size when rendering occurs, so the rounded corners will show up correctly.

**How this had needed to be handled**

I don't know what version of iOS you need to support (since this issue has been fixed in recent versions), but here is one of the ways to work around the issue where the cell was not initially laid out properly until you scrolled off-screen, then back on-screen.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Workaround for visible cells not laid out properly since their layout was
    // based on a different (initial) width from the tableView.

    CGRect rect = cell.frame;
    rect.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds);
    cell.frame = rect;

    ... configure cell

    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    return cell;
}
```

You may be able to get away with `setNeedsLayout`; `layoutIfNeeded`.  In my app, I had needed the constraints to be updated for other reasons.

Comment: This issue was still occurring for me even after I moved the offending code into willDisplayCellAtIndex on iOS 8.1.x and on 9.1.x. I tested it on iOS 10.2.x and the issue didn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm modifying a table view cell during a call to tableView:cellForIndexPath, but the modifications do not appear until the cell is scrolled off and then back on.

This method won't be called until the cell needs to be recycled (i.e appears from off-screen). Cells already in the tableview don't have this method called since they are already visible. I'm wondering (since this code works fine) if you have confused the delegate callback? These methods only trigger when a new cell scrolls into view (and a cached cell
 needs to be reconfigured).

if you call `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;`
 you would be able to trigger a redraw on a cell, or `[tableview reloadData]` to refresh all cells

Comment: Since this method is responsible for providing the dynamic data for the cell, it doesn't make sense that it's only called when a call "reappears". Also, I've tried `[tableview reloadData]` and it has no impact on causing the mask to appear. I think the answer does indeed lie with the use of `willDisplayCell` as referenced in the previous question.

Comment: The cells are recycled UIViews. Put a breakpoint on the in cellForRowAtIndex and you will see. If you want them to have dynamic content you have to supply a subclassed UITableViewCell that updates itself. This method is merely used to bring a new cell onto the view; it asks you for a cell when it needs to add one to the table (i.e it scrolls into view). Once you give it a cell it is your responsibility to update it - this is simply how the API works

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.reloadInputViews()
}
```

Comment: Hi JG. Welcome to StackOverflow. How about an explanation? This is too minimal to be considered a quality answer. Regards.